# refine lines and rects output mondrianish image error

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror

I use mondrianish to draw Mondrian-style image and I would like to get fine control on the lines and rectangles. However, I experience errors when I am applying the lines and rects into the generate_image function.

I use mondrianish 0.5.3 module.
https://pypi.org/project/mondrianish/

I input:

```
from mondrianish import generate_image, generate_grid 

colors = ("#FFF8F0", "#FCAA67", "#7DB7C0", "#932b25", "#498B57")

lines, rects = generate_grid((20, 10), density=0.3)

with open("output-1.png", "wb") as f:
    generate_image("png", (lines, rects), 10, colors, f)
```

Error comes out:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:/Users/Peter Chung/Desktop/MyScript/Python/MondrianScript.py in <module>
      6 
      7 with open("output-1.png", "wb") as f:
----> 8         generate_image("png", (lines, rects), 10, colors, f)
      9 

~/anaconda3/envs/finviz/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mondrianish/__init__.py in generate_image(format, size, stroke_width, colors, stream)
    266 
    267   # Generate image data.
--> 268   grid_size = (int(round(size[0]/stroke_width/7)), int(round(size[1]/stroke_width/7)))
    269   if grid_size[0] < 3 or grid_size[1] < 3: raise ValueError("Stroke width is too large.")
    270   lines, rectangles = generate_grid(grid_size)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I tried to change the type of lists and rects but all have similar error. Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: `lines` and `rects` are lists.  You can's pass them to `generate_image` as the `width` and `height`.  You need to pass numbers, e.g. `(200, 100)`, not a pair of lists.

Comment: @TomKarzes ok, I know it now, but what if I want to change the lines and rects and then put them back to the code and generate image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is in @Tom Karzes comment, the function `generate_image` expects an iterable with 2 numbers for the `size` parameter.

Looking into the mondrian code, specifically line 268, you can see that it tries to index the size parameter and expect a number to come out.

If you want to, you can modify the function `generate_image()` and have it acept a user generated grid.

There are many ways to do that, but I think replacing lines 268 through 270 in `__init__.py` with the code below should work:

```
try:      
    grid_size = (int(round(size[0]/stroke_width/7)), int(round(size[1]/stroke_width/7)))
    if grid_size[0] < 3 or grid_size[1] < 3: raise ValueError("Stroke width is too large.")
    lines, rectangles = generate_grid(grid_size)
except TypeError:
    lines, rectangles = size
```

This is just a quick fix, but it will solve your problem for now.

Comment: thanks, but I want to increase the lines and rectangles and keep the size, I think I don't know how to input the modify lines and rects integer into the generate_image function.

Comment: To do that, you need to take `lines` and `rect` and modify the coordinates, than feed them back to the `generate_image` function, modified as I suggested above. `lines` and `rect` are simply a set of coordinates

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
I think I got the similar error with replacing the script